# "Since I was in Japan" or "since I left Japan"

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, american-english

> I last ate raw fish when I was in Japan.

> => I haven't eaten raw fish since I was in Japan.
> or
> => I haven't eaten raw fish since I left Japan.

I  think the second one is correct, isn't it?

Comment: They have the same meaning, because of the word "since."

Comment: I would find the first more natural, but neither is 'incorrect'.

Comment: Raw fish?!! I hope they cook the chips.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, but the former is more natural.

Note: You may also find that sometimes people would say "I haven't eaten raw fish since Japan" implying "since I was in Japan" and assuming the listener knows you have been Japan (and/or that you have eaten raw fish there). For example: I often say things to my wife like "I haven't eaten jerk chicken since Jamaica." She infers "since we were in Jamaica" and I know that she knows I ate jerk chicken there. So it's almost a casual/shorthand way to say it.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. The first one implies a link between being in Japan and eating raw fish, and the second implies a link between leaving Japan and not eating raw fish. It depends where you want to put the emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct.

'Since' is a conjunction of time. We can use *since* to introduce a subordinate clause.

Five years *have passed* since I last *saw* her.

They *have played* better since he *joined* the team.

I *have known* her since I *lived* in Japan.

I *have known* her since I *was* in Japan.

I **haven't eaten** raw fish since I **was** in Japan.

I **haven't eaten** raw fish since I **left** Japan.